# laravel deployment generating autoload error

Tags: git, laravel, composer-php

I have cloned a laravel project on a sub-directory of my shared server (bluehost). But when i go into the folder through ssh and try to run composer update
`php-cli ~/composer/composer.phar update`
it does the the updating then after displaying  `generating autoload files` it gives `Status: 500 Internal Server Error` and a long string of html. What is wrong here?

Removed Vendor directory and ran update again. Same error.

Added alias php="php-cli" to .bashrc and tried a fresh install on a subdirectory. This is also giving a 500 Internal server error

Comment: does the files have necessary permissions?

Comment: yes. That should not be a problem. the clone went just fine

Comment: 1. php composer.phar self-update if composer is not updated.
2. change "minimum-stability": "stable" at composer.json

Comment: just installed composer yesterday. checked composer.json. minimum-stability is set to stable already

Comment: Let's remove the vendor directory completely & rerun composer.phar update. It's all I can suggest now.

Comment: Delete the bootstrap.php file. that might do it.

Comment: Well if you don't give us the exact error (in the HTML) is a wild guess... as @Anindya said, maybe you've to give permission for the web server to write in the log/cache whatever files?